# Learning Blender

Tags: modeling

Hello I recently have been having trouble learning to model in blender.

I know how to use the program and understand its interface but have trouble putting those skills together to create the desired effect.

Do you guys have any suggestions on the best way to learn this.

Thank you.

Comment: For me it was helpful to start from following beginners modelling tutorials to catch a workflow, then increase difficulty, till I managed to figure out what works for me and what tools and workflows suits me the best.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn to use the skills you have is to try to use them. Try to find a few time laps on youtube.com and try to remake what they did, and if you get stuck you do have the time laps that you can go back to and see what they did.
It will probebly be a god ide to learn art basic just fore the part that is "Have a vision on what to do and know how to do it"